# Export = class statement with class implements interface

Tags: class, interface, typescript

I want to define both a class and an interface in one file, but I want to export with `export = Foo` because if I use `export default Foo` the exported object is `{ default: Foo }` instead of the actual class object.

So I want to do this:

```
interface IFoo { bar():boolean; }

class Foo implements IFoo { bar():boolean { return true } }

export = Foo;
```

But then you get the error `Extends clause of exported class 'Foo' has or is using private name 'IFoo'.`

How can I export the class directly and still have it extend an interface defined in the same file?

Comment: foo.ts: `export default Foo`

other.ts: `import Foo from "./foo.ts"`

Answer (score 0):

1. In `export = Foo;` style:

   You should write the import: `import { Foo } from "module"`
2. In `export default Foo;` style:

   You should write the import: `import Foo from "module"`